# find the Bijective function that answers the criteria: [0,1] -> [0,1) union [3,4]

Tags: group-theory, functions

find the Bijective function that takes elements of [0,1] (the numbers between 0 and 1 included) and matches exactly one element in the set [0,1) $\bigcup$ [3,4] (notice that 1 is not defined.

the big issue here is not including [1,3) in the bijection.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider $f(x) = 2x$ for $x\in [0,1/2)$ and $f(x) = 2x+2$ for $x\in [1/2, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=2x$ for $x\in[0,1/2)$ and $f(x)=2x+2$ for $x\in[1/2,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Map $[1/2,1] \mapsto [3,4]$. This is easy $\dfrac{f(x)-3}{4-3} = \dfrac{x-1/2}{1-1/2} \implies f(x) = 2x+2$.

Now map $[0,1/2) \mapsto [0,1)$. This is even more easy by setting $f(x) = 2x$.